# hover effect is not working with hr tag

Tags: html, css, animate.css

Hey guys I am trying to make a page which is having six buttons. I want the caption under the image will slide in on mouse over event.I am using animate.css for this.

My problem is when I use <hr> tag my hover effect is not working. If I removed this Its working properly but I want to use both together.

I also tried <div> tag and border-top property of css but any element whichever I used in-between the caption and image will cause stop working hover effect.

I tried to change the size of image and increasing the padding but it is not working. Is there any idea that how to do it?

This is my html code:

```
<div class="btn-row">
    <a href="domainSearch.html">
        <div class="box-btn">
            <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img"><hr class="caption-border">
            <div class="caption animated slideInUp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Institution</div>
            </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
.caption{
display: none;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.5em;
color: $txt-lightgrey;
position: absolute;
margin: -10px 0px 0px -75px;
}

.img:hover + .caption{
  display: inline;
}
```

Here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dipeshraichana/hwunxuy5/)

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `.caption` directly after `.img`.

Use `~` instead of `+`.

```
.img:hover ~ .caption {
    display: inline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hwunxuy5/1/

Comment: may i know.. what is the use of ~ and + .. can you please explain me? thanks

Comment: @saina: `+` is next sibling, in this case `hr` after `.img`, `~` general sibling (in this case we 'skipped' `hr` and fire `.caption` element).

Comment: @saina: maybe http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_sibling.html and http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_adjacent.html

Comment: I understood from your jsfiddle.

Okay, then ..if i want to set background color for second and fourth div means.. what to do? thanks

Comment: @saina: you should create own question. If you need 2th and 4th element, `use :nth-child, :nth-of-type`, etc., http://caniuse.com/#search=nth, or you can use a spaghetti selector like `:first-child + div, :first-child + div + div + div` to target 2nd and 4th element.